# Caught: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space - Using -Xmx not applicable

Tags: groovy, jvm, out-of-memory

I have written a very complex database migration script in Groovy, that runs just fine on my workstation but produces "Caught: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" when run on the server's JVM. JVM is stuck as is (limited resources as an intern), so I need to figure out another way to fix this besides increasing available memory.

The error strikes when some of the largest tables are accessed: a particularly large, but simple, join (200,000+ rows to 50,000+ rows). Is there another way I can approach such a join that will save me from the error?

Example of query:

```
target.query(""" 
    SELECT 
        a.*, b.neededColumn 
    FROM 
        bigTable a JOIN mediumTable b ON 
    a.stuff = b.stuff 
    ORDER BY stuff DESC 
""") { ResultSet rs ->
    ...
}
```

Comment: @Fernandez I am not sure, I have no experience with cursors.

Comment: can you provide the relevant part of the code where you're making the db call?

Comment: @Fernandez I added an example. It's exactly what I do just with names changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you run the join in SQL on the database server?

If not, you're probably stuck with iterating through each of your 200,000 results joining it to the 50,000 rows and writing out the results (so you aren't storing more than 1*50,000 results in memory at any one time)

Or, if you have access to multiple machines, you could divide your 200,000 items into blocks and do one block per machine?

***Edit***

Taking your example code, you should be able to do:

```
new File( 'output.csv' ).withWriter { w ->
  target.eachRow( '''SELECT a.a, a.b, a.c, b.neededColumn FROM
    bigTable a
    JOIN mediumTable b ON a.stuff = b.stuff
    ORDER BY stuff DESC''' ) { row ->
    w.write "$row.a,$row.b,$row.c,$row.neededColumn"
  }
}
```

That will write each row out to the file `output.csv`

Comment: Will this even help? I'm not sure, but I was under the impression that the memory problem was related to the join, not the results?

Comment: If you're wrong, then yes it will help. I don't have your data, your systems or your memory restrictions, so you're in a better position than me to try it out

Comment: True enough Tim. I am having some trouble adapting your example unfortunately, as my code relied heavily on the use of the ResultSet. I'll post if I get something to work. Until then I'll accept your answer, thanks.

Comment: Give me a shout if you get stuck, and I'll try to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your code so that the rows are not loaded all into memory at the same time (i.e. stream the data, work on each row one at a time). As far as I know, Groovy still doesn't do this when you use things like `collect`, so rewrite it to use a for loop.